# How to inactivate an eclipse plug-in without uninstall it?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

How to inactivate an plug-in in Eclipse Kepler SR2 without uninstalling it?
I have a plug-in for Android, which is pretty big and causes eclipse starting slow.
But I need the plug-in on some other projects.
In Help -> About Eclipse > Installation Details -> Installed Software, 
there is only an option to uninstall.
Can I simply inactivate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily disable a plugin simply by moving its directory out of Eclipse's plugins directory.

In Eclipse, if you select Help | About | Installation Details | Plugins, the list of plugins has 2 columns 'Version' and 'Plug in Id'. The corresponding plugin subdirectory will have the format id_version. So you can simply move this directory out of the plugins directory, restart Eclipse, and it should start without loading this plugin.

Of course, if other plugins that are loaded depend on the missing plugin, you may get errors during startup.